# What should I use to pass value in asp.net mvc posting form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am passing the edited `value` and retrieving it back but I dont get back the `id` value.. how do I get back the value for Id...The id value will actually remain the same..all I need to do is pass it back again...

```
 public ActionResult EditValue(int id)
     {
      ViewData["id"]=id;
      ViewData["Value"]=GetOriginalValue();
      return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditValue(string Value)
     {
     //How do I get the id value back..it will always be the same
      UpdateValue(id,Value);
    }
    //---VIEW--
    <% Html.BeginForm(); %>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <%= Html.Label("Value")%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%= Html.TextBox("Value",ViewData["Value"])%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Value")%>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" />
            </p>
                 <% Html.Hidden("id", ViewData["id"]);%>   
            <% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put `int id` into your parameters for the post, it should pick up the hidden form element... Or you can use the [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) class and access the individual form elements.

So your method signature would look like:

```
public ActionResult EditValue(int id, string Value)
```

or

```
public ActionResult EditValue(FormCollection form)
```